# Retrieving the Name from the same row using a recently acquired ID

Tags: sql

I was messing around and wanted to know (title). Let me explain.

Let's say I have an Employee table and in that table is `ID ManagerID and Name ID`. So after making the Query to find everyone's manager you are left with something like this as a result

```
Person's Name | Their ID | Manager ID
```

Now he's what I want to know if it is possible. The managers are also in this employee table and they either have other employees as their manager or they dont have a manager. So technically I have all the information I need at my disposal. Just need to exchange the int (ManagerID) with the Person's name that is in the same row.

Is that possible or is SQL not able to handle that kind of swapping.

Edit: 
So here's the test table and values I've been using:

```
Create table Employee
(   ID int,
    Name varchar (50), 
    ManagerID int );

Insert into Employee
Values( 101, 'Joe Smoeington', 102);

Insert into Employee
Values( 102, 'This Guy', 106);

Insert into Employee
Values(103, 'Test', 102);

Insert into Employee
Values(104, 'Rob', 105);

Insert into Employee
Values(105 , 'Jeremy', NULL);

Insert into Employee
Values(106 , 'Sam', NULL);
```

---

My stuck point:
Select ID, Name, ManagerID
From Employee
Where ManagerID IS NOT NULL

Ultimately this will get you a table that looks like this:

```
ID      Name       ManagerID
101 Joe Smoeington  102
102 This Guy        106
103 Test            102
104 Rob             105
```

Things Ive tried:

```
Select ID, Name, ManagerID
From Employee Join Employee
On Employee.ID = Employee.ManagerID
Where ManagerID IS NOT NULL

Select ID, Name, (Select Name From Employee Where (didnt know what to put here and gave up on this attempt)
From Employee
Where ManagerID IS NOT NULL
```

There are others just not worth mentioning

Comment: for starters, include your table structure and post your attempt at solving this

Comment: you need to do a left outer join to the same table

Comment: Apologies this was hypothetical for the most part I can make a table structure I suppose.

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL or Oracle? Please fix your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **self join** something like this.

```
 SELECT T1.Name AS Employee_Name,T1.ID AS Employee_ID,(IFNULL(T2.ID,'NA')) AS ManagerID
    FROM
    employee T1
    LEFT JOIN employee T2 ON T1.ManagerID = T2.ID
```

**EDIT** : 
   IF you want to see only those employee who has manager.

```
 SELECT T1.Name AS Employee_Name,T1.ID AS Employee_ID,(IFNULL(T2.ID,'NA')) AS ManagerID
            FROM
            employee T1
            INNER JOIN employee T2 ON T1.ManagerID = T2.ID
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949aa/1)

hope This Helps.

Comment: Thank you for explaining self join. I made the mistake before of only trying to name 1 of the tables not both. This is really cool.

Comment: Woah didn't notice all of the new stuff till just now. Will read through it. Thank you again

Comment: I can't my rep is too low. I'm still new

Comment: Since you have product specific SQL, and no dbms tagged in question, please specify which dbms this works with!